# overriding equals in superclass but not in subclass?

Tags: java, class

I have overridden `equals()` and `hashCode()` in my ClassA.

```
ClassA {
   //overridden equals() and hashCode()
}
```

ClassB extends ClassA.

```
ClassB extends ClassA{
   //....
}
```

Now if my code calls `classBInstance.equals(classBInstanceTwo)`, does this call ClassA's `equals` method?

Thanks!

Comment: You could easily make a test program to find out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it does.
But this can easily break the equals/hashcode contract ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)). For Example:

a equals b == b equals a

a equals b == a equals c == b equals c

So in the class B you shouldn't add new fields, which you want to use in equals/hashcode.

A possible solution is to use Class A as a field in Class B.

In the book Effective Java of Joshua Bloch there is a nice article about the problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. All methods in Java are virtual by default.

Comment: Except static methods.  That are sorta virtual on Tuesdays.

Comment: (And constructor methods also behave a bit strangely.)

Comment: Thanks for giving more accurate definitions! ;) Maybe you are such an expert in Spring? I have an open question about very strange basic auth behaviour. Would be great if you help)